# SQLGrammarException when inserting a table with single column as serial using JPA

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee, informix, openjpa

I have a table say `Book` with only one `column(book_id)` as `Serial`. 
I am using Informix and openejb 4.7.2. 
When I am trying to create a new entry in DB, i am getting error

```
OpenEJB - EjbTransactionUtil.handleSystemException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1387) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.19.Final.jar:4.2.19.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1310) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.19.Final.jar:4.2.19.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1316) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.19.Final.jar:4.2.19.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:881) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.19.Final.jar:4.2.19.Final]
    at org.apache.openejb.persistence.JtaEntityManager.persist(JtaEntityManager.java:149) ~[openejb-core-4.7.2.jar:4.7.2]
```

**Book.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "book")
public class Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "book_id", nullable = false)
    private short bookId;

    public short getBookId() {
        return bookId;
    }

    public void setBookId(short bookId) {
        this.bookId = bookId;
    }

}

public class DocumentTemplateDAO{
    @Override
    public Book create(Book entity) {
        LOG.debug("Entity is created {} ", entity);
        this.entityManager.persist(entity);
        this.entityManager.flush();
        return entity;
    }
}
```

Code to create book

```
Book book = new Book();
documentTemplateDAO.create(book);
```

The query that is going to be executed is

`insert into book values ( )`

Answer (score 0):

2 potential solutions:

- Informix SERIAL (if this is what your book id is in the database) takes a zero to trigger the autoincrement, it should affect @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO).
- IBM developed a specific Hibernate dialect for Informix, which you can download there: http://members.iiug.org/opensource/.

Sorry, I don't have more right now, hopefully, it will put you on the right track.